# After change from C# to Python i don't understand bool values in while loop

Tags: python, loops

I am learning python after changing from C#.
I don't understand why my code is doesn't work.

```
import MyFunctions


def main():
    game = True
    while game:
        trials = 1
        number = MyFunctions.Generate_random_number()
        print('Próba numer:', trials)
        userNumber = int(input('Podaj liczbe z przedzialu od 1 do 100: '))

        while MyFunctions._is_valid(number, userNumber) != True:
            trials += 1
            print('Próba numer:', trials)
            userNumber = int(input('Podaj liczbe z przedzialu od 1 do 100: '))
        answer = input('Czy chcesz kontynuować grę? "tak" lub "nie" tutaj przed while')
        while (answer != 'tak') or (answer != 'nie'):
            print('tutaj')
            answer = input('Czy chcesz kontynuować grę? "tak" lub "nie"')
            print(answer)
            if answer == 'nie':
                game = False


main()
```

After adding string to "answer" variable i go in to the loop to check the answer and when i write "tak" and loop is checking bool variable i go to the loop again. It should stop and go to the first loop. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 4):

The problem seems to be this:

```
while (answer != 'tak') or (answer != 'nie'):
```

This loop conditional will always evaluate to `True`, because `answer` cannot be equal to both `'tak'` and `'nie'` at the same time.

It looks like you've maybe started with something like an until loop (I don't know what constructs exist in C#) and tried to invert the logic to use in a while loop and made a mistake.

Instead, it should probably be:

```
while (answer != 'tak') and (answer != 'nie'):
```